# Java Swagger with Play - error: package io does not exist

Tags: java, playframework, swagger-2.0

I'm using Java Play 2.5
and I'm trying to add the Swagger plugin to my project.

In build.sbt I added the following code:

```
libraryDependencies += "io.swagger" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.5.3"
```

In application.conf I added the following:

```
play.modules {
  enabled += "play.modules.swagger.SwaggerModule"
}
```

Then I ran `"sbt clean compile"` - 
It compiled successfully.

But when I try to use it in my code:

```
import io.swagger.*;
```

I get the following error:

```
"error: package io does not exist"
```

Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: I figured it out. In case anyone has the same problem, and using java, make sure to add also the swagger core in the build.sbt file: 
libraryDependencies += "io.swagger" % "swagger-core" % "1.5.3"